# Linear Algebra Wizardry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normal-distribution, matrix-equations

I am reading a textbook which features results on the multivariate normal distribution and the author writes out results with no justification, which take me a page to verify, and they end up being right. These claims don't seem obvious to me. I'll give an example.

Here's the setup:

Let $y_1,y_2,...,y_n, \mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$, let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$

Let $Y$ be the $n \times d$ matrix, formed by taking row $i$ to be $y_i$.

Let $e \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a vector of 1's.

An example of a claim:

$\sum_{i}(y_i-\mu)^{T}A(y_i-\mu)=\text{trace}(A(Y-e\mu^{T})^{T}(Y-e\mu^{T}))$

This claim took me a long time to verify, but the author included zero justification and just followed it on from his last line of work. There are more examples of claims he makes which would take me a while to verify, but I feel like I might be missing a trick given the frequency of this happening.

Can anyone explain how either I can get better at doing these, or at least some verification that I'm not crazy and it's not super trivial?

Many thanks.

Comment: The only way I know to get better at using the trace and blocked multiplication... is practice.  Eventually you can eyeball results like that... though I’d always suggest a change of variables $\mathbf z_i:= \mathbf y_i -\mathbf \mu$

Comment: Sometimes you know that an expression like this must exist, and so if you're doing your own working you take 15-20 minutes to figure it out. When you're reading it in other people's working, they've done the work for you!

Comment: The trick is to get comfortable with [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) and the properties of trace.  What the author does to prove this claim is simply recognize the sum in question as the result of such a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short derivation of the identity in question.

$$
\sum_{i}(y_i-\mu)^{T}A(y_i-\mu) = 
\sum_{i}\operatorname{tr}[(y_i-\mu)^{T}A(y_i-\mu)]\\
= \sum_i [\operatorname{tr}A(y_i-\mu)(y_i-\mu)^{T}]
= \operatorname{tr}\left[ A\sum_i(y_i-\mu)(y_i-\mu)^{T}\right].
$$
Now, note that
$$
\sum_i(y_i-\mu)(y_i-\mu)^{T} = \pmatrix{y_1 - \mu & \cdots & y_n - \mu} \pmatrix{(y_1 - \mu)^T \\ \vdots \\ (y_n - \mu)^T} = (Y - e\mu^T)^T(Y - e\mu^T).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Being familiar with some properties of trace might help.

We know that $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$ and $Tr(A+B)=Tr(A)+Tr(B)$

\begin{align}
\sum_i (y_i - \mu)^TA(y_i - \mu) &= \sum_i Tr((y_i - \mu)^TA(y_i - \mu)) \\
&=\sum_iTr(A(y_i - \mu)(y_i - \mu)^T) \\
&=Tr(\sum_iA(y_i - \mu)(y_i - \mu)^T) \\
&=Tr(A\sum_i(y_i - \mu)(y_i - \mu)^T)\\
&=Tr(A\left[y_1-\mu, \ldots y_n-\mu \right]\left[y_1^T-\mu^T, \ldots y_n^T-\mu^T \right]^T)\\
&=Tr(A(Y-e\mu^T)^T(Y-e\mu))
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone explain how either I can get better at doing these

The same way you get better at doing anything else - by practice.

---

> or at least some verification that I'm not crazy and it's not super trivial?

It's not trivial at the slightest, but that's not the criterion. It's not about "is it trivial", it's about "is it interesting enough".

Let me explain.

The book you read was not **about** linear algebra, it was about something else, in your case, it sounds like probability. When writing a book about one subject, it is usually best if the author includes as little of other subjects as possible, while still keeping the book understandable. The derivation of the claim you cite is a purely algebraic manipulation that the author did not consider **interesting** enough to include.